# List Array to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, list, datatable

I have a List of String[], which I am trying to convert to a dataset/datatable using LINQ.
I parsed the text file to list, in which the first row has 4 columns and others have data associated with columns.

Everything comes up as an array in the list.

List[10] where List [0] has string[4] items.

```
List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines(s)
    .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
    .Select(line => line.Split(';'))
    .ToList();

DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.AddRange(list.First().Select(r => new DataColumn(r.Value)).ToArray());

list = list.Skip(1).ToArray().ToList();

list.ForEach(r => table.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));
```

The LINQ doesn't accept the Value property.

Can some one suggest the simple and efficient way for this implementation?

Comment: *"The LINQ doesn't accept the Value property"* -- can you describe your own perceptual, subjective experience of LINQ failing to accept the Value property?

Comment: I used the value property when working with dictionaries.. so the columns are added to the table if its the first row.. not sure how to handle the List here.. Plz advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.String` doesn't have a property named `Value`.

If you want to create a column for each item in the first row, just give it the strings:

```
table.Columns.AddRange(list.First().Select(r => new DataColumn(r)).ToArray());

//  You don't need ToArray() here. 
list = list.Skip(1).ToList();

//  Get rid of Value in this line too, and you don't need 
//  .Select(c => c) either -- that's a no-op so leave it out.
list.ForEach(row => table.Rows.Add(row.Cast<object>().ToArray()));
```

There's no Dictionary here. `list.First()` is an array of strings. When you call `Select` on an array, it just passes each item in the array to the lambda in turn.

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Select()` passes the lambda a series of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. Different class, different behavior.

Comment: thank you, its adding first row as columns.. how do i add rows to the datatbale in foreach using List  list.ForEach(r => table.Rows.Add(r.Select(c => c.Value).Cast<object>().ToArray()));

Comment: @user1046415 I updated, but think about it: If the only problem with the first one was that `Value` didn't belong there, then what should you try first with the other line? Both of them are selecting the items in string arrays from the same list.